# Circular progress bar with countdown timer in Android

Tags: android, android-progressbar, countdowntimer

I want to show a circular progress bar with countdown timer.And the timer starts from 10 mins to 0.In the Textview i am showing timer and that is working fine.
But it is not reflecting in the progressbar.Progress bar is not at all changing.
Below is the code which i have tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ProgressBar barTimer;
    CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    TextView textTimer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        barTimer = findViewById(R.id.barTimer);
        textTimer = findViewById(R.id.textTimer);
        barTimer.setProgress(100);
        startTimer(10);


    }

    private void startTimer(final int minuti) {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(60 * minuti * 1000, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;
                barTimer.setProgress((int)seconds);
                textTimer.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds/60) + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds%60));
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if(textTimer.getText().equals("00:00")){
                    textTimer.setText("STOP");
                }
                else{
                    textTimer.setText("2:00");
                    barTimer.setProgress(60*minuti);
                }
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

xml code

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textTimer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/barTimer"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textTimer"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress"

        />
```

Can anyone please tell me where it is wrong and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scaling factor is not correct and hence your maxProgess and setProgess values are also incorrect.There are two ways to fix this.

1.Set seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 600 and not 1000.

Let's say X% = 1 second then 100% = 60 seconds,then X% = 100/60 seconds but we are calculating in milliseconds
hence X% = 100/(60*1000) = 1/600 milliseconds.
Also we have set 60 seconds for 100% hence multiply your setProgess and setMax by a factor 10.Since 600 seconds is 10 minutes.

```
barTimer.setProgress(1000);
barTimer.setMax(1000);

long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 600;
```

2.Similar to above rather than dividing by 600 divide 6000.
seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 6000;

Let's say X% = 1 second then 100% = 600 seconds(10 mins),then X% = 100/600 seconds but we are calculating in milliseconds
hence X% = 100/(60*1000) = 1/6000 milliseconds.

Now since we are directly calculating for 10 mins no need to multiply your setProgess and setMax by any factor.

```
barTimer.setProgress(100);
barTimer.setMax(100);

long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 6000;
```

Also I would suggest setting countDownInterval to 1 sec rather 0.5 sec.

Hope this helps.
Please mark the answer as accepted if it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much @udit7395.I have tried the 2nd approach and it is working.One issue is there in the textview timer is starting from 01.39.How can i show there 10 mins like 10.00?

Comment: @Ravikumar Use the leftTimeInMilliseconds given by onTick. 
If problem is not fixed please create/ask a new question and I will solve it there as answering question in comments is against stackoverflow guidelines.

Comment: Okay @udit7395 . I will try this.But circular progress bar is not smooth,can you tell me how to make it smooth?

Answer (score 0):

So i run your code and found it was the time that you are giving is causing the issue , in reality `progressbar` is doing its work , but because you are giving the time of 10(minutes) initially the process is too slow that you cannot see it doing work , try changing it to **1** for the testing sake and you will see progress bar moving.

```
startTimer(10);
```

To

```
startTimer(1);
```